# Not able to loop in php socket

Tags: php, sockets

while looping the client socket array, if the socket is echoed as is, it displays "resource id# 23" etc etc different resources for each client, but when the socket_write function is called to write the same echo message in each loop, the write function fails, and only one of the clients get the message written( ders an input box, if u give an input and submit, it goes to socket server and writes d message for all clients)

```
<form method='GET' action="">
<input type='text' name='name' />
<input type='submit' />
</form>
<?php
$no=500;$n=0;
$sock=null;
if(!($sock=socket_create(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0)))
{
    $code=socket_last_error();
    $msg=socket_strerror($code);
    die("ERROR $msg");
}
echo "Socket created $sock";
/*

$sock1=socket_create(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
socket_set_option($sock1, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
socket_connect($sock1,'localhost',9001);
if(sizeof($_GET)>0)
{
    $msg=$_GET['name'];
    if(!socket_send($sock1,$msg,strlen($msg),0))
    {
        $err=socket_last_error();
        $emessg=socket_strerror($err);
        die("ERROR $emessg");
    }
}
*/
if (!socket_set_option($sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)) { 
    echo socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)); 
    exit; 
} 
if(!socket_bind($sock, "127.0.0.1" , 9001) )
{
    $cod=socket_last_error();
    $msg=socket_strerror($cod);
    die("ERROR:$msg");
}
echo "Socket BOund";
if(!socket_listen($sock,10))
{
    $cod=socket_last_error();
    $msg=socket_strerror($cod);
    die("ERROR:$msg");
}
echo "Socket listen OK \n";
class clients{
public $addr=null,$portc=null,$soc=null;
function __construct($sock1)    {
/*if(!($client[$n]=socket_create(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0)))
{
    $code=socket_last_error();
    $msg=socket_strerror($code);
    die("ERROR $msg");
}*/
$this->soc=$sock1;
if(socket_getpeername($this->soc,$address,$port))
{
    echo "$address in port $port";
    $this->addr=$address;
    $this->portc=$port;
}
                    }

function sock(){return $this->soc;}
}//$client[500];
$client=array();
while(true){
//$client[$n++]=socket_accept($sock);
if($clienttemp=socket_accept($sock))
{
    $client[$n]=new clients($clienttemp);
    echo "NEw client ".$client[$n]->addr;
    $n++;
    //var_dump($client[$n-1]);
}
for($j=0;$j<$n;$j++)
//if($input=socket_read($client[$n-1]->soc,1024))
if($input=socket_read($client[$j]->soc,1024))
{
    //$resp="<br/>****".$client[$n-1]->addr." says: $input*****";
    $resp="<br/>****".$client[$j]->addr." says: $input*****";
    if($input=='quit')break;
    for($i=0;$i<$n;$i++)
{
    socket_write($client[$i]->soc,$resp);
    echo "****</br>$resp".$client[$i]->soc."****</br>";
}
}

// TO write in all clients


}
socket_close($client[$n-1]->soc);
socket_close($sock);

?>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do, and what is your question?

Comment: Should display ie write the message in all the clients

Comment: It might help if you indent and format your code. I think your problem lies in the line: for($j=0;$j<$n;$j++) as there is no opening accolade ({) for the for loop. But its somewhat hard to tell with messy code like this..

Answer (score 0):

Johan mentioned that there is no opening accolade for your for loop. In this instance, that's ok because it will only execute the next **expression** which happens to be an **if** block containing the rest of your logic.

You may be able to see the issue though using [socket_strerror](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-strerror.php) and [socket_last_error](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-last-error.php).

In this code block (formatted, and with comments removed):

```
for($j=0;$j<$n;$j++)
   if($input=socket_read($client[$j]->soc,1024))
   {
      $resp="<br/>****".$client[$j]->addr." says: $input*****";
      if($input=='quit')break;
      for($i=0;$i<$n;$i++)
      {
        // Get write response
        $sent = socket_write($client[$i]->soc,$resp);
        // Check response for error
        if($sent === false) 
        { 
           $err = socket_strerror(socket_last_error($client[$i]->soc));
           echo("\n $err \n");
        }
        echo "****</br>$resp".$client[$i]->soc."****</br>";
      }
    }
```

That should help you identify the cause of the failure.